# Server clone loading test page

Tags: nginx

I've cloned one of my Rackspace Cloud Servers (running centOS) and set it up on a new subdomain, but when I browse to it, I get the "Welcome to NGINX on Fedora!" test page, while the original server loads my Node.js app as expected.

I've verified the following:

- The same processes are running on both servers
- Node.js and MongoDB are running (checked via `sudo systemctl status [process_name]`)
- The same PM2 processes are running with no errors
- The `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file is the same as the original server's
- Hitting the server's IP address directly loads a different/the same page as the original server

Clone server's `server` block:

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
}
```

As a front-end dev, I'm not an NGINX expert, and I don't have any error logs to show, but if you guys can guide me, I'm sure I can provide whatever I need to diagnose the issue further.

Comment: you need to edit the default server{} block to listen for your new subdomain on the new clone.

Comment: @Dave That makes perfect sense, but I don't see any reference to the original subdomain in the `server` block (updated my question). I also checked in /etc/nginx/default.d/ and there are no additional .conf files.

Comment: `listen       80 default_server;` and `server_name  _;` tell the server to listen to all domain names hitting that server on any ip on port 80. take a look at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts I know its relating to ubuntu but the config can be cloned/created accordingly.

Comment: You forgot to set the upstream to listening node.js processes, checkout: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/tutorials/pm2-nginx-production-setup